# store values in array to POST with selected checkboxes

Tags: php, arrays, post

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '  <td><input name="types[]" type="checkbox" value="' . $row['type'] . '" /></td>';
  echo '  <td>' . $row['type'] . '</td>';
  echo '  <td><input size="3" type="text" name="quantities[]" id="TBox-' . $TBCounter . '" /></td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
```

it's hard to find on the internet for this solution. 
how do i store selected checkboxes value into types[] and quantities[]?

i would like to do a POST in php

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9118304/773702

Comment: In case you've missed it, I've provided an answer to your question that you might want to have a look at

Answer (score 1):

> how do I retrieve the types[] and quantities[]

So you want to know how to determine which of the `types[]` checkbox values are checked, and store those values in an array?

You'd retrieve all the checkboxes by name, then loop through while checking the `checked` property

```
var selected = [];
var allCbs = document.getElementsByName("types[]");
for(var i = 0, max = allCbs.length; i < max; i++)
    if (allCbs[i].checked === true)
        selected.push(allCbs[i].value);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. how do i store .value into types[] in this case?

Comment: You want to store all values from checked 'types[]' checkboxes?  The above code should do that

Comment: but can i get the types[] in my php file with $_POST?

Comment: So after you get the checked types into an array, you then want to post them back to a different request?

Comment: its all in a form, so i assume i need to get the name attributes in the form to do a $_POST..

Comment: @vinz - check my answer for a way to retrieve your information using $_POST

Answer (score 0):

By using [$_GET or $_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php) on the page that you're POSTing to.

Comment: sorry rephrased my qns. how do i store selected checkboxes value into types[] and quantities[]?

Answer (score 0):

[HTML Input Forms – Sending in an array in PHP](http://www.johnrockefeller.net/html-input-forms-sending-in-an-array-in-php/)

Comment: sorry actually i meant storing selected values of checked boxes into array

Answer (score 0):

When you click submit button of this form, all checked values will be sended by method that you declared:

something like `<form name="name" method="Post" action="file.php"> ... </form>`.

Then inside `file.php` you can get types as array: `$_POST['types']`. This array will contain checked values