# how can i get the value of the loop both text fields and hidden fields in php using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

How can I get the values of each input field (both hidden and visible) using jQuery?

```
<?php 
     $date   = date('m-d-Y');
     $ts     = strtotime($date);
     $year   = date('o', $ts);
     $week   = date('W', $ts);

     for($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++) {
     ?><td><?php
     $ts = strtotime($year.'W'.$week.$i);
     ?><input type="text" name="days" id="days" />
      <input type="hidden" name="date_now" id="date_now" value="<?php print date("Y-m-d", $ts); ?>" />
    </td><?php
    } 
?>
```

Comment: your rendered html is going to have multiple *unique* `id`'s...

Comment: @ahren how to solve the problem. can you give me example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing the id='days' and id='date_now' to classes (class='days' and class='date_now') assuming you want all the values, we can put them into an array like this:

```
var days_array     = [];
var date_now_array = [];

$('.days').each(function() {
    days_array.push($(this).val());
});

$('.date_now').each(function() {
    date_now_array.push($(this).val());
});
```

now the variables `days_array` and `date_now_array` contain all the values.

Comment: The problem is that the `for` loop makes multiple elements with the same `id` attribute. You won't be able to properly select them all like this.

Comment: ahh i see, that's kind of bad practice to have duplicate id's (should be using classes instead), but i'll change my answer

Comment: will i am not use something like .each function because when i am surfing the net,.,.i just encounter the .each function

Comment: can you give me an example anyway,.,.thankz because i want to get the values of the text field and hidden field and save it to my db,.,as duration and date_reported

Comment: @webghost: You won't be able to use `.each()` until you fix the `id` issue. The `id` attribute should be unique (one id per element and one element per id), so you'd have to change `id` to `class`.

Comment: easiest way, would be to change the id to class instead. would you want me to make an example of that?

Comment: i would expand my question if you dont mind,,.how can i pass this values to something like $.post(blabla..) and get the pass values using php..,thankz

Comment: that would be an entirely different question. but you just use those values for the object you would pass to $.post

Answer (score 2):

Are all the inputs produced by the loop intended to be submitted as part of one form?  Why not collate them [into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314567/how-to-get-form-input-array-into-php-array)?

Change the names from `days` to `days[]` and from `date_now` to `date_now[]`, respectively.

When embedding php control structures directly into html, consider using the [alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) for more clarity.

If you embed the current loop counter to the id of each input, you'll be able select each one individually.

If you add a `class` attribute to each input, you can select them as a group.

You can eliminate the extra assignment to `$ts` in each loop iteration by passing the result of [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) directly to the second parameter of [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Since it's not totally clear what your ultimate intent was, here is your initial code sample modified with all of my suggestions applied:

```
<?php 
$date = date('m-d-Y');
$ts = strtotime($date);
$year = date('o', $ts);
$week = date('W', $ts);

for($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++): 
$dt = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($year.'W'.$week.$i));
?>
<td>
<input type="text" name="days[]" id="days<?=$i?>" class="days" />
<input type="hidden" name="date_now[]" id="date_now<?=$i>" value="<?=$dt?>" class="date_now" />
</td>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

From the above code, you can either select one of the inputs individually like this:

`$("#days3").val();`

Or, you can select all of the hidden inputs like this:

```
var dates_now = [];
$(".date_now").each(function(i, input) {
    dates_now.push(input.val());
});
```