# How to get the value from text box with a array names at post method in php?

Tags: php

I'm new in PHP developing.

I have a looping textbox

```
$i = 0;
while($row_recordset = mysql_fetch_array($query_run)) 

{
    echo "<tr>";

    echo "  <td>{$row_recordset['REGNO']}</td>
            <td>{$row_recordset['NAME']}</td>

            <td><input type='text' name='atten_ave".$i."'></td>

         ";

    echo "</tr>";

$i++;

 }
```

and as you can see I assign a different names in the textbox via array.

I want to echo the value of the textbox into another page to check if it submit the data before I insert it into the database, But there is an error after I execute the page.

```
$atten_ave = $_POST['atten_ave'.$i];

echo $atten_ave;
```

Here's the error

```
Notice: Undefined variable: i in BLAH BLAH BLA

Notice: Undefined index: atten_ave in BLAH BLAH BLAH
```

I already change the error_reporting in php.ini and set the E-NOTICE

But the error still exist.

I also try to suppress notice errors by putting '@' before the `$atten_ave = $_POST['atten_ave'.$i]`. But there is no value that was submitted, even I input a value at the textbox.

Comment: print_r($_POST); and tell what is the output

Comment: this has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314567/how-to-get-form-input-array-into-php-array

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: @vimalnath Array ( [atten_ave0] => [atten_ave1] => [atten_ave2] => [atten_ave3] => [atten_ave4] => [atten_ave5] => [atten_ave6] => [atten_ave7] => [atten_ave8] => )

Comment: oops array values are empty!

Comment: thanks anyway i use this $i = 0;
foreach ($_POST as $textboxname => $values) {
   
   echo 'Primary=' .$textboxname. ' ------------ ' . 'Values='.$values;
   echo '<br>';
   $i++;
}

Answer (score 1):

That is correct error, because after submitting the form you don't have a variable `$i`. You need to loop the `$_POST` variable like this

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($_POST as $val) {
   $atten_ave  = $val.$i;
   $i++;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, what If sir I have a 3 or more textbox? how can I decalre the given textbox name at the post method. ex$i = 0
foreach ($_POST(WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE?) as $val) {
   $atten_ave  = $val.$i;
   $i++;
}

Comment: int that case give text field name for each like this foreach($_POST['filedname'] as $val) { $variablenam = $val.$i;} something like this

Comment: $chandresh_cool thanks sir for the reply, but in my fieldname I set the names into array to give different name in every textbox, for example <input type='text' name='atten_ave".$i."'> the '$i' is auto incrementing, what should I declare at the ($_POST[''] as $val)? I try this but $_POST['atten_ave'.$i] it gives me a error " Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: if you have only this then just give this foreach($_POST as $val) {$atten_ave = $val.$i; $i++; }

Comment: put semicolan on first line. i mean $i=0;

Answer (score 0):

Another thing: if you close your eyes, you can't see things around you but it doesn't mean they are not there. You are trying the same with notices: you try to hide them instead of get rid of them...