# How to email Dynamic Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, email, post

I've checked so many questions and forums but I couldn't figure out how to email an array.

This will be an Order Form for products. Users can add new order rows by jquery.

So here is my shortened example;

form.php

```
<input type="text" name="array[][id]" />
<input type="text" name="array[][partno]" />
```

on email.php;
I can see that, it Posts all the array by

```
<?php var_dump($_POST['array']); ?>
```

But i couldn't figure out how to email it.
This is what i tried in email.php which is wrong ;

```
$id = $_POST['array'][]['id'];
$partno = $_POST['array'][]['partno'];
```

and

```
$email_message .= "Id: ".clean_string($id)."\n";
$email_message .= "Part No: ".clean_string($partno)."\n";
```

What should I do to send the values in that array

EDIT:
I tried but I couldn't figure out where to put @onetrickpony codes. Here is the whole code of email.php

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
 
// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = "a@a.com";
$email_subject = "order";

function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}
 
// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
    !isset($_POST['array'])) {
        
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }
 
$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
 
function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}
 
$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
?>
<?php var_dump($_POST['array']); ?>
<?php
}
?>
```

---

#### Solution

As I understand it was unnecessary to use `array[][input_name]` ..
I changed input names as;

```
"partno[]" ..etc
```

also added

```
!isset($_POST['partno']) || ..etc and,
$partno = $_POST['partno']; .. etc
```

to necessary places,
and removed;

```
!isset($_POST['array'])
```

and for the Key part;

```
foreach( $partno as $key => $no ) {
$email_message .= $no;
$email_message .= $partnumber[$key];
$email_message .= $quantity[$key];
$email_message .= $partname[$key]."\n";
}
```

According to the answer of @Jeffrey Blake in the question topic;
[How to get form input array into PHP array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314567/how-to-get-form-input-array-into-php-array?rq=1)

Comment: How do you want it to look?

Comment: Just use a `foreach` loop on `$_POST['array']`.

Comment: @Wrikken As again it should be line by line, like;
id partno
id partno

Comment: @jeroen i dont't know how to use it :(

Comment: Why are you calling it array? You don't need those extra indexes, do you?

Comment: @PHPglue don't mind the id it can be Quentity or anything else, not for index.

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer of its own, thank you.

Comment: Hello @Cœur; Thank you for your notice, but I couldn't figure out where the exact place is to put the solution. If you guide I will be appriciated by following the rules.

Answer (score 3):

`[]` is used to assign values to an array in PHP.

By the way the inputs are named, it looks like you should be able to access it like this:

```
$id = $_POST['array'][0]['id'];
$partno = $_POST['array'][0]['partno'];
```

But if you have more than one entry you'll have to iterate it. Something like:

```
foreach($_POST['array'] as $item){

   $id = $item['id'];
   $partno = $item['partno'];

   $email_message .= "Id: ".clean_string($id)."\n";
   $email_message .= "Part No: ".clean_string($partno)."\n";
}
```

Comment: I am trying to implement

Comment: I couldn't make it work :(
Please check http://crea-direct.com/post/
This is without your codes

Comment: on the page your input names are different

Comment: I know i changed them here to English, but in php side everything is correct.

Comment: By the way; if I use [0] on form.php and email.php it sends only the first row data.
If i use [] on both it gives error

Comment: All right, i figured out.. It is working now..
$id = $_POST['array'][0]['id'];
$partno = $_POST['array'][0]['partno']; are after $telephone...  foreach is after $email_message for telephone.

Thanks for your great support guys.

Comment: But you didn't use  $id = $_POST['array'][0]['id'];
$partno = $_POST['array'][0]['partno'];  in your link?

Comment: No, because it appears you can have more than one row. I mentioned that you should use a loop in this case. `$_POST['array'][0]['id']` would select the ID field from the first row only

Comment: Hmm, yes the main purpose is multiple rows. We just tried it for 2 colums and worked. But it sent 8 rows when i filled 2.. I should reverse correct answer check

Answer (score 1):

I think your code should look more like:

```
<input type='text' name='lookHere[]' />
<input type='text' name='lookHere[]' />

$lh = $_POST['lookHere'];
$email_message .= 'Id: '.htmlentities($lh[0], 3, 'UTF-8')."\n";
$email_message .= 'Part No: '.htmlentities($lh[1], 3, 'UTF-8')."\n";
```

Note that 3 is `ENT_QUOTES`. You can replace this using the proper quote style and charset, if need be. Personally, I would use the **PHPglue** Library at https://www.PHPglue.com .

Comment: I'm sure your way is also working my friend but im not good at PHP and trying to learn.