# php mysql save input array

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

Im having trouble with this php mysql issue. I have 5 input fields with the same name, and foreach input field entered i was that to be saved in the database. But at the moment, if i input 2 fields, its inserting them plus 3 blank ones. How do i just insert the ones which are not empty

here is the html

```
<input type="text" name="tags[]" placeholder="Add Tags" />
<input type="text" name="tags[]" placeholder="Add Tags" />
<input type="text" name="tags[]" placeholder="Add Tags" />
<input type="text" name="tags[]" placeholder="Add Tags" />
<input type="text" name="tags[]" placeholder="Add Tags" />
```

here is the php

```
 $tags = $_POST['tags'];

    for($i = 0; $i < count($tags); $i++){
                 $tag = $_POST['tags'][$i];

                 $addtags = $gifs->addtags($tag, $id);
              }
```

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314567/how-to-get-form-input-array-into-php-array

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You can use **[foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)**

```
$tags = $_POST['tags'];
foreach($tags as $tag) {
  $tag = trim($tag);
  if (! empty($tag)) {
    $addtags = $gifs->addtags($tag, $id);
  }
}
```

Comment: this won't do what OP is asking, if tag[4] is empty it will be sent to addtags anyway

Comment: @sathia, Please check OP requirment, he want to avoid empty insertion into table, this solves his problem!

Comment: a) there's no sanitisation of input, b) if the tag is just a space it will be sent to addtags c) if the tag is empty it will be sent to addtags, your foreach is doing the same thing as OP's one

Answer (score 0):

well, first thing is to sanitize your input, second thing is to trim each value and add this:

```
$tag = trim($tag);
if(!empty($tag)){
 ...code
```

Comment: What do you think that trim() is going to do? I totally get and agree with the !empty but nowhere does the OP say that it should not allow entries with a space

Comment: it will trim the variable, removing spaces and other non visible chars in order not to create empty/duplicated tags. what is a tag made of vertical tab good for?

Comment: what if a user submits this tag: \t\n\n\t, do OP wants this tag?

Comment: That is a question for the OP, all I'm saying is that we do not know enough about the real world usage to make any assumptions about what are valid characters in the input. The only case the user mentions is empty values

Comment: yeah, I understand your point, but simply reading the code it's obvious he doesn't want invisible characters. at least, I hope so

Comment: @sathia, Same point for you, Where is your  sanitisation of input code?

Comment: i said Sanitisation first, thought it was obvious :) ciao

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    $tags = $_POST['tags'];

for($i = 0; $i < count($tags); $i++){
             $tag = trim($_POST['tags'][$i]);
    if (!empty($tag))
             $addtags = $gifs->addtags($tag, $id);
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the empty with `array_filter()`:

```
$tags = array_filter($_POST['tags']);

foreach($tags as $tag) {
    $addtags = $gifs->addtags($tag, $id);
}
```

Comment: good idea, but again, this won't prevent invisible characters to be posted.