# Getting results from a dynamically created form using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, forms

I have created an online form which allows a user to input the number of different products they want to return & then enter details about that product.

It's never known how many form input fields will be passed to a PHP script to process the form as it depends on the number of products the user wants to return & store the results into an MySQL database.

The way I was thinking of passing all form fields to the PHP script was by looping through the number of form fields via JavaScript & storing that figure in a hidden form input field then passing that to the PHP script & using that number to set-up a loop to iterate through the inputs.

I hope this makes sense & any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314567/how-to-get-form-input-array-into-php-array) what you're trying to do?

Comment: Sounds like a sound solution. Go ahead and build it.

Comment: The way I would handle this is probably set a variable in front of the field name, example product_ID#_variable.  Loop through your $_POST and locate each individual product_, then parse out the ID# and the variable.  Determine what's filled out and what isn't.  Send back errors if the user is missing information.

Comment: @ChrisG easier to just name every input like : `name="myform[txt_name]"` and so on. Then U don't need to do the scraping in the `$_POST`

Comment: @DarkBee that works as well. I just like parsing out everything in $_POST to be extremely strict with what information is posted.

Comment: Is it okay to have multiple form fields using the same name & storing the value of each into an array then passing that to a PHP variable to loop through?

Comment: I don't see why not, I always do this with checkboxes as well