# parsing dynamic POST variable

Tags: php

I have a form that may submit 1 line item or 200 to quote. using FPDF to create results and everything is working perfectly, but I was looking for a way to automate picking up post values. So far I have been doing them manually, which is very difficult to make code changes:

```
//conditional statement to verify values exist, otherwise we write a blank line
$item=$_POST['item3'];
$uprice=$_POST['uprice3'];
$udprice=$_POST['udprice3'];
$quan=$_POST['quan3'];
//add values to report
//repeat for next result
$item=$_POST['item4'];
$uprice=$_POST['uprice4'];
$udprice=$_POST['udprice4'];
$quan=$_POST['quan4'];
```

I was wondering if there is a way to add a variable inside the post value, like $_POST[$nextitem]?

Comment: $_POST is an array, so you could foreach it.

Comment: looping `$_POST` itself would loop every 'row' multiple times... it's still possible, but not the best solution in this case imo.

Comment: Have you tried google your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop until the next number is not available anymore:

```
<?php
$i = 1;
while (isset($_POST['item' . $i])) {
    $item = $_POST['item' . $i];
    $uprice = $_POST['uprice' . $i];
    $udprice = $_POST['udprice' . $i];
    $quan = $_POST['quan' . $i];

    // do your stuff

    $i++;
}
```

concatenating a string `'var'` with int `1` will result in a string `'var1'` in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I would just grab the entire array with `$array = $_POST` and then use `foreach()` loops to manipulate it later.

Alternatively, it sounds like you have an arbitrary number of things on your form. Do it like this:

```
<input type="text" name="item[]" />
<input type="text" name="quan[]" />
<input type="text" name="udprice[]" />


<input type="text" name="item[]" />
<input type="text" name="quan[]" />
<input type="text" name="udprice[]" />


<input type="text" name="item[]" />
<input type="text" name="quan[]" />
<input type="text" name="udprice[]" />


<input type="text" name="item[]" />
<input type="text" name="quan[]" />
<input type="text" name="udprice[]" />
```

You can see more about this in this very helpful answer: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3314567/1415625)

When you submit this arbitrary number of fields, you will end up with a nice multi-dimensional array. Iterate over it like this:

```
$i =  count($_POST['item']);
$payload = array();
while ($i <= count($_POST['item']) {
    $payload[] = array(
       'item' => $_POST['item'][$i],
       'udprice' => $_POST['item'][$i],
       'quan' => $_POST['quan'][$i]
    );
    $i++;

}
```

Now `$payload` is a fancy array that can be inserted into databases and such.