# Processing dynamic number of inputs in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pdo

I have a similar form as [here](http://snipplr.com/view/12647/).

It has a dynamic number of inputs, e.g.

```
<li><input type="text" name="friend_1" id="friend_1" /></li>
<li><input type="text" name="friend_2" id="friend_2" /></li>
<li><input type="text" name="friend_3" id="friend_3" /></li>
<li><input type="text" name="friend_4" id="friend_4" /></li>
<li><input type="text" name="friend_5" id="friend_5" /></li>
</ol>
<input type="button" value="Add Friend Field" onclick="addField('friends_area','friend_',10);" />
```

Usually, when you want to process a form, you will refer
to certain form variable as `$_POST['friend']`.

1. Is there a way to collect all `$_POST['friend_X']` into an array? (note that there may be gaps)
2. and insert it into an `MySQL table`? Is it possible with one insert statement (I'm using PDO) or should I do it with for loop?

Comment: You can iterate over `$_POST` :-) the rest depends on whether you insert a single or multiple records

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get form input array into PHP array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314567/how-to-get-form-input-array-into-php-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to post as an array such as

```
<li><input type="text" name="friend[]" id="friend_1" /></li>
<li><input type="text" name="friend[]" id="friend_2" /></li>
<li><input type="text" name="friend[]" id="friend_3" /></li>
<li><input type="text" name="friend[]" id="friend_4" /></li>
<li><input type="text" name="friend[]" id="friend_5" /></li>
```

Then serialize the array using [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) to save to your database.

Comment: Beat me to it :-) But please don't store serialized data like that, it wil make retrieving data and searching the database a nightmare.

Comment: Under most circumstances you are absolutely right, however to avoid the next question being "How come my insert breaks when i try to add post to db" this would be the simplest answer.

Comment: Ah, you've been here before ;-)

Comment: When I have the label `for` attribute associated with the input `name` attribute, how could I do it now? Associate it with the input `id` attribute?

Comment: @xralf How have you associated the label with the `name` attribute? Normally it is automatically associated with the ID.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you use an array in html to begin with, all your values will be in an array as well:

```
<li><input type="text" name="friend[1]" /></li>
<li><input type="text" name="friend[2]" /></li>
<li><input type="text" name="friend[3]" /></li>
<li><input type="text" name="friend[4]" /></li>
<li><input type="text" name="friend[8]" /></li>
<li><input type="text" name="friend[9]" /></li>
```

In php `$_POST['friend']` will be an array with the indices you set (if you set them). If you don't set the indices, they will simply start at 0.