# PHP for loop concatenation

Tags: php

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 1; $i++) {
    $you_item[$i] = ucwords($_POST['you_item'.$i.'']);
    $you_item[$i] = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=570&currency=1&market_hash_name=".$you_item[$i]."";
    $you_item[$i] = str_replace(' ', '%20', $you_item[$i]);
    $you_item[$i] = file_get_contents($you_item[$i]);
    $you_item[$i] = json_decode($you_item[$i], true);
    $you_item[$i] = $you_item[$i]['median_price'];
    $you_item[$i] = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]{2,8};/i","", $you_item[$i]);
    echo $you_item[$i];
}
```

the sample site is this http://bit.ly/1gKGoN0

I have a problem on the loop of getting the value from the textboxes

i declared the form like this

```
<?php for($i=1;$i<=15;$i++){ ?> <input type="text" name="<?php echo
"you_item".$i.""?>" /> <?php } ?>
```

but the problem now is i cant get the value from the textboxes where i forwarded to $you_item[$i].
the site that i made doesnt have a loop. i coded the $you_item1 upto 15 because i have 15 textboxes.
can someone help me out?

Comment: You should use arrays for input elements. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314567/how-to-get-form-input-array-into-php-array

Comment: You made a mistake naming your input field. Its name corresponds to `you_item1`, `you_item2` and that's not how we do things. Your fields should be declared like this: `<input type="text" name="you_item[]" />`. When submitted to the PHP script, you'll have an array in `$_POST['you_item']` that you can access via numeric indexes, such as   `$_POST['you_item'][0]`, `$_POST['you_item'][1]` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change,

```
<?php for($i=1;$i<=15;$i++){ ?> <input type="text" name="<?php echo
"you_item".$i.""?>" /> <?php } ?>
```

to

```
<input type="text" name="you_item[]" />
```

Comment: how about the for($i = 1; $i <= 1; $i++) {
    $you_item[$i] = ucwords($_POST['you_item'.$i.'']);
    $you_item[$i] = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=570&currency=1&market_hash_name=".$you_item[$i]."";
    $you_item[$i] = str_replace(' ', '%20', $you_item[$i]);
    $you_item[$i] = file_get_contents($you_item[$i]);
    $you_item[$i] = json_decode($you_item[$i], true);
    $you_item[$i] = $you_item[$i]['median_price'];
    $you_item[$i] = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]{2,8};/i","", $you_item[$i]);
    echo $you_item[$i];
}

Comment: you are not getting the actually, we can write as many number of text boxes like <input type='textbox' name='textboxvar[]' value='Option One'>1<br>
    <input type='textbox' name='textboxvar[]' value='Option Two'>2<br>
    <input type='textbox' name='textboxvar[]' value='Option Three'>3, and get all the entered values by running loop over $_POST['you_item'][$i]