# PHP POST/GET as associative arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, post, get

I'm have 4 forms that I want to share the same action. When the PHP starts, I'm trying to get the value of my array before I run the code. The array name should represent the column name that I want to update and the value will be the column value. I've tried this `echo $_GET[0];` but it doesn't return the value I'm looking for.

**My question is twofold:**

1. Is there a way to call the values as an associative?
2. If there is(I'm sure I'm just doing something silly here), how do
   I identify the name of the variable?

Thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314567/how-to-get-form-input-array-into-php-array might be a help

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I needed. Please post it as the answer and I'll definitely vote up!

Comment: thank you, I've added my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To harness PHP's built-in support for automatic associative array generation directly from HTML FORM, here is a brief introduction:

http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays

The following form will populate a multi-dimensional `$_POST`.

```
<form method="POST">
  <input name="words[]" value="...">
  <input name="words[]" value="...">

  <input name="foo[bar][]" value="...">
  <input name="foo[bar][]" value="...">
  <input name="foo[bar][]" value="...">

  <input name="values[0][0][]" value="...">
  <input name="values[0][0][]" value="...">
  <input name="values[0][0][]" value="...">
</form>
```

`$_POST` will be similar to

```
$_POST = [
  "words" => [
    0 => "...",
    1 => "..."
  ],
  "foo" => [
    "bar" => [
      0 => "...",
      1 => "...",
      2 => "..."
    ]
  ],
  "values" => [
    0 => [
      0 => [
        0 => "...",
        1 => "...",
        2 => "..."
      ]
    ]
  ]
];
```

Also, there is a related SO question that might be a help too:

[How to get form input array into PHP array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314567/how-to-get-form-input-array-into-php-array)

Answer (score 0):

Try `var_dump($_GET);` You will see all variables.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: I have and I have verified that the variables are posting. It's just one variable that holds an on/off value. I should have posted this as well