# How to group HTML from with multiple fields with same name

Tags: php, html

I work on from to add more than one device when user click on add more
But How can I group multiple fields with same name as array for every device from this form, my server side language is PHP.

```
<form>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="widget stacked">
      <div class="widget-header">
        <i class="icon-hdd"></i>
        <h3>Remove Devices</h3> <a class="btn label label-success add_new_device">Add more</a>
      </div>
      <div class="widget-content">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="device_name">Device Name</label>
          <input class="form-control" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="max128" data-validation-optional="true" name="device[device_name][]" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="device_description">Device Description</label>
          <input class="form-control" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="max255" data-validation-optional="true" name="device[device_description][]" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="device_url">Device Url</label>
          <input class="form-control" data-validation="url" data-validation-optional="true" data-validation-help="Ex: http://000.000.000.000/index.cgi" name="device[device_url][]" type="url">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="device_ip4">IP4</label>
          <input class="form-control" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="max15" data-validation-optional="true" data-validation-help="Ex: 000.000.000.000" name="device[device_ip4][]" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="device_ip6">IP6</label>
          <input class="form-control" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="max45" data-validation-help="Ex: 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000" name="device[][device_ip6]" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="device_username">Device Username</label>
          <input class="form-control" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="max128" data-validation-optional="true" name="device[][device_username]" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="device_password">Device Password</label>
          <input class="form-control" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="max128" data-validation-optional="true" name="device[][device_password]" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="widget stacked">
      <div class="widget-header">
        <i class="icon-hdd"></i>
        <h3>Remove Devices</h3> <a class="btn label label-success add_new_device">Add more</a>
      </div>
      <div class="widget-content">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="device_name">Device Name</label>
          <input class="form-control" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="max128" data-validation-optional="true" name="device[device_name][]" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="device_description">Device Description</label>
          <input class="form-control" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="max255" data-validation-optional="true" name="device[device_description][]" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="device_url">Device Url</label>
          <input class="form-control" data-validation="url" data-validation-optional="true" data-validation-help="Ex: http://000.000.000.000/index.cgi" name="device[device_url][]" type="url">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="device_ip4">IP4</label>
          <input class="form-control" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="max15" data-validation-optional="true" data-validation-help="Ex: 000.000.000.000" name="device[device_ip4][]" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="device_ip6">IP6</label>
          <input class="form-control" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="max45" data-validation-help="Ex: 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000" name="device[][device_ip6]" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="device_username">Device Username</label>
          <input class="form-control" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="max128" data-validation-optional="true" name="device[][device_username]" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="device_password">Device Password</label>
          <input class="form-control" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="max128" data-validation-optional="true" name="device[][device_password]" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="widget stacked">
      <div class="widget-header">
        <i class="icon-hdd"></i>
        <h3>Remove Devices</h3> <a class="btn label label-success add_new_device">Add more</a>
      </div>
      <div class="widget-content">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="device_name">Device Name</label>
          <input class="form-control" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="max128" data-validation-optional="true" name="device[device_name][]" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="device_description">Device Description</label>
          <input class="form-control" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="max255" data-validation-optional="true" name="device[device_description][]" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="device_url">Device Url</label>
          <input class="form-control" data-validation="url" data-validation-optional="true" data-validation-help="Ex: http://000.000.000.000/index.cgi" name="device[device_url][]" type="url">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="device_ip4">IP4</label>
          <input class="form-control" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="max15" data-validation-optional="true" data-validation-help="Ex: 000.000.000.000" name="device[device_ip4][]" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="device_ip6">IP6</label>
          <input class="form-control" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="max45" data-validation-help="Ex: 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000" name="device[][device_ip6]" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="device_username">Device Username</label>
          <input class="form-control" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="max128" data-validation-optional="true" name="device[][device_username]" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="device_password">Device Password</label>
          <input class="form-control" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="max128" data-validation-optional="true" name="device[][device_password]" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name your fields like `devices[0][description]`, `devices[1][description]` and so on.

If every object has the exact same number of fields and every one is a new record - you can use `devices[][description]` and browser will fill indexes for you, but this can lead to bugs in the future, if you decide to use same form for editing records.

Also see [How to get form input array into PHP array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314567/how-to-get-form-input-array-into-php-array)