# PHP update array to string

Tags: php, mysqli

This is my code

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
  $sql = 'UPDATE checklist_programs
  SET PROGRAM_ID='.$_POST['PROGRAM_ID'].'
  WHERE CHECKLIST_ID = ?';
  $query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
  if($query)
  {
    echo "Record update successfully";
    header('Location: OverViewCheckList.php');
  }
```

I got an error like this

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\checklist\updateChecklist.php

Comment: line 4 SET PROGRAM_ID='.$_POST['PROGRAM_ID'].

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that `$_POST['PROGRAM_ID']` contains an array itself.  If the form that is posting to this program has multiple fields with the name `PROGRAM_ID[]`, this will happen.  See [How to get form input array into php array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314567/how-to-get-form-input-array-into-php-array) for an example of how this works.

Also, see the related post about how to prevent SQL injection in PHP.