# Why does my form delete the last row rather than the selected one?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

In my code it first shows result of table and then it will delete the data upon submit. But there is issue that wherever I click in delete button I will always deleting last row. It does not delete specific row which I want to delete

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "1234";
$db = "ptcl";
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);
```

end connection

html code

```
  <html>
 <body>
<div class="content">
<div class="exchange">
    <center>EXCHANGE /NTE</center>>
<center>
<form action="delete.php" name="delete" method="POST">
<table border="1">
<tr><th rowspan="2">EXCHANGE TYPE</th>
    <th colspan="9">DESCRIPTION</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">Retail</td>
    <td>DTEs</td>
    <td>Retail/Sett</td>
    <td>Online</td>
    <td>Offline</td>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td colspan="2">Action</td>
</tr>
```

form which i want to show first then delete by its id

```
    <?php   
    global $con;
    $query="select * from exchange ";
    $result =$con->query($query);

    if($result->num_rows > 0){


while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){?>

<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['exchangetype']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['retail']?><td>
     <td ><?php echo $row['dte']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['retail_sett']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['retail']+$row['dte']+$row['retail_sett']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['offine']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['retail']+$row['dte']+$row['retail_sett']+$row['offine']?></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete"/></td>
          <td><input type="hidden" name="eid" value="<?php echo $row['eid']?>" />  
    </td>
    <?php } 
    ?>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
    </center>
 <?php  } else{
echo "No record found";
        }

   ?>       
</div>
   </div>
```

php delete code starts

```
global $con

$eeid = $_POST['eid'];

if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $query = "DELETE FROM exchange WHERE eid='$eeid' ";

    if ($con->query($query) === true) {
        echo "DELETED Data";
    } else {
        echo "error during deletion" . $con->error;
    }
}
```

It will not delete which I want to delete it delete only last row.

Comment: Drew Bro if u know where is the issue then plz tell me.

Comment: Where do you set $eeid ?

Comment: $eeid=$_POST['eid']; before the delete query

Comment: Ok, if you dump the POST value just before the delete query, does it correspond to the value you want to delete ?

Comment: You have multiple `name=eid` in the form. When you submit the form, `$_POST['eid']` will just be the last one.

Comment: You need to start and end a `<form>` tag for every loop in that `while`

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability against your `root` database user - don't put this on the internet just yet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Issue with your code is the hidden type you are using it always over write older values and set your last value as its value
USE GET method to overcome the issue

```
<td><a href="delete.php?row_id=<?php echo $row['eid']?>" /></a></td>  
 </td>
```

In delete.php or whatever your file name use this code

```
//mysql_connection
if(isset($_GET['row_id'])){
 $eeid=$_GET['row_id'];
 $query="delete from exchange
       where eid='$eeid' ";

if ($con->query($query)===TRUE){
  echo "DELETED Data";
  }
  else{
  echo "error during deletion".$con->error;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: bro in updation i wil do same thing but it will empty them when i update it.

Comment: `    if(isset($_GET['row_id'])){
      $eeid=$_GET['row_id'];
 $exchangetype=$_POST['exchangetype'];
 $retail=$_POST['retail'];
 $dte=$_POST['dte'];
 $retail_sett=$_POST['retail_sett'];
 $offine=$_POST['offine'];
 
      $query="Update exchange SET exchangetype='$exchangetype', retail='$retail', dte='$dte', retail_sett='$retail_sett', offine='$offine' 
   where eid='$eeid'";`

Comment: one minute i am checking

Comment: That's not the way to do updation

Comment: but its work and it will empty all the data when i click on hyperlink of update . in the field i use same name as above.

Comment: pass your id to any page and select all data from mysql using that id and display it .use a hidden type to store the id and change values and use submit to update.when you update use your hidden id to update.

Comment: Sir its not working or may be I don't understand because I'm beginner in this field . last question can I use form??? and can i use 2 ids?? and using isset which id name i use? (update or id )? thanks.

Comment: hi check this tutorial http://www.freezecoders.com/2012/11/add-list-edit-delete-record-in-database-using-php.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're repeating the hidden input in the form, and they all have the same name. When you submit the form, `$_POST['eid']` will just be the last one.

You need to have a separate form for each row, not one form for the entire table, so that the submit button will just submit that one `eid`.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){?>

<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['exchangetype']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['retail']?><td>
     <td ><?php echo $row['dte']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['retail_sett']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['retail']+$row['dte']+$row['retail_sett']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['offine']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['retail']+$row['dte']+$row['retail_sett']+$row['offine']?></td>
    <td><form method='post' action="delete.php">
            <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="eid" value="<?php echo $row['eid']?>" />  
        </form></td>
    <?php }
```

Another option would be to put the EID into the submit button's value, rather than a hidden field.

```
<td><input type="submit" name="delete" value="<?php echo $row['eid'] ?>">/</td>
```

Then `delete.php` would do:

```
$eeid = $_POST['delete'];
```

Comment: ... or, for the sake of completeness, the OP could use [array fields](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3314578/472495).

Comment: @halfer How would he know which one's submit button was clicked on?

Comment: The number in the square brackets e.g. `<input type="text" name="item[1]" />` is usually the primary key of the row being rendered. This will be transformed by PHP as a nested array e.g. `[ 'item' => [ 1 => 'value' ] ]`.

Comment: @halfer When he submits the form, `$_POST` will contain *all* the `<input type="hidden" name="eid[$i]" value="$row['id']">` values.

Comment: OK, he/she can do this: `<input type="submit" name="delete[5]" value="Delete"/>` without the hidden field (and obviously varying the number to whatever PK for each row).  PHP will populate the array as something like `[ 'delete' => [5] ]` depending on the delete button clicked on.

Comment: @halfer Actually, there's a simpler method like that. I just updated the answer with it.