# JQuery clone is not working with class selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0z88cwtw/)

I am trying to clone a span from the onClick() function of a button. First time this works fine but when I try second time it is not cloning. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the essence of my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.addmachinerow').on('click',function(){

    var edcname =  $('.edc_name option:selected').val();
    var machine_description =   $("input[name='machine_description'").val();
    var capacity =   $("input[name='capacity'").val();
    var voltage_level =   $("input[name='voltage_level'").val();
    var powertype =  $("select[name='typeofpower'").val();
    var edcautovalue = $('.ecaddingspan').attr('data-value');

//if($('#bank_increment').html() == '')  $('#bank_increment').html('0');   else  $('#bank_increment').html(parseInt($('#bank_increment').html())+1);

//if($('#bank_clickededit').html() == '') var bank_increment =  $('#bank_increment').html(); else  var bank_increment = $('#bank_clickededit').html();


$('.ecaddingspan').clone().appendTo('.edcparent');
//$('.bankname, .bankbranch , .IFSCcode , .bankaccno , .accsincefrom').val('');

 var edc_details = {'edcname' : edcname, 'machine_description' : machine_description, 'capacity' : capacity, 'voltage_level' : voltage_level, 'powertype' : powertype }
//$('.bank_details_array').append(JSON.stringify(bank_details)+'&&');
    });
});
```

Additionally:

How can i clone the entire sets on clicking the Total clone button ?

I need to save the values in array with different names. Is that possible ?

Comment: When you clone the ".ecaddingspan" element you create another. Next time around your selector finds 2 elements instead of one so you need to use a first selector maybe.

Comment: how to do that ? where im going wrong ?

Comment: See my answer for explanation of your first issue. Please edit your question and remove parts 2 & 3 and open another question on those points.Multi-part questions are confusing for later readers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can i clone the entire sets on clicking the Total clone button ?

You've to use event delagtion `on()` instead :

```
$('body').on('click','.addmachinerow', function(){
   //Event code
})
```

Since the new `.addmachinerow` added to the page dynamically after the clone.

> I need to save the values in array with different names is that possible ?

I suggest the use of the array name `[]` like :

```
<input name='machine_description[]' />
<input name='voltage_level[]' />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Its working fine :) . But im getting duplicates how can i avoid that one ?

Comment: can you help me with the demo

Comment: how to get the values and save in array using jquery ? with this `machine_description[]`

Comment: can u please check the fiddle link ? && fiddle link  =  https://jsfiddle.net/0z88cwtw/

Comment: Do you want to sent data to php page ?

Comment: You want to send all the data? What about `serialize()`?

Comment: i dont know how to do that. can you give me the demo ?

Comment: Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0z88cwtw/1/ .. `$('form[name="edc_name"]').serialize()` will gives you all the data in all the forms. (to get the data in the PHP side check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314567/how-to-get-form-input-array-into-php-array)

Comment: `edc_name%5B%5D=1&machine_description%5B%5D=sdf&capacity%5B%5D=sfdsf&voltage_level%5B%5D=sfsfsf&typeofpower%5B%5D=1&machine_description%5B%5D=sdf&capacity%5B%5D=sfdsf&voltage_level%5B%5D=sfsfsf&typeofpower%5B%5D=1` what's this `%5B%5D`??

Comment: It's the `[]` you should just submit the data the php will read it as shown in the other ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314567/how-to-get-form-input-array-into-php-array )

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
   
       $('.cloneitem').not('.cloned').clone().addClass('cloned').appendTo('body');
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p class="cloneitem">This is a paragraph.</p>

<button>Clone all p elements, and append them to the body element</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not correct - click the clone button twice gives double the paragraphs !

Comment: Better - but the OP is using a class selector - not an id. The ID selector will use only the first matching element whilst the class selector will process ALL matching elements. This is the source of the OP's issue.  Try again.

Comment: Getting better but not really explaining the OP's core issue. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is a common misconception of JQuery selectors. If you play with ID selectors then switch to class selectors then you often don't notice a difference in behaviour. The [ID selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) doc says

> ID Selector: If more than one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID will only select the **first** matched element in the DOM

whilst for the [class selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

> Class Selector: Selects **all** elements with the given class.

What this means is that when you clone the target element you get away with a subsequent ID selection (JQuery ignores the duplicates) but a subsequent class selection will trip you up if you were not expecting JQuery to return multiple matches. Class selectors are great for grouping elements but not so great for cloning.

While I am on the soap box - whenever you use the clone function you should consider and fix the potential duplicate ID and un-required class duplicates that you are producing. Duplicate ID's are definitely bad show - duplicate classes may actually be by design but you should still consider them.

In the code sample below I assign the class `iAmSpartacus` to the original span which the onClick() function then clones. Each clone also gets the `iAmSpartacus` class so I remove it from each new clone to ensure that the `$(".iAmSpartacus")` selector always returns a maximum of one element. The spans show their current `class` property to prove the point.

```js
// this runs one - shows us classes of original span
var origSpan=$(".iAmSpartacus")
origSpan.html("My classes are: " + origSpan.prop("class")) 

$("#daButton").on("click", function(e) {
  
  var newSpan = $(".iAmSpartacus").clone();
  newSpan.removeClass("iAmSpartacus");  // remove the dup targetting class
  newSpan.appendTo('.edcparent');
  newSpan.html("My classes are: " + newSpan.prop("class")) 
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="daButton">Click me</button>
<div class="edcparent" style="border: 1px solid red;">
    <span class="ecaddingspan iAmSpartacus" style="display: block;">I am a span</span>  
</div>
```