# Put the value of every field with the same name attribute into an array using PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have two fields (at minimum) that both have the same name attribute. Using a little jQuery, the user can add more text boxes using jQuery's `.clone()` feature. Every possible input they add will have the same name attribute as the first two. 
I want to try to use php to create a comma separated list of every input value after the form is submitted.

```
$competitor_names = $_POST['competitor-name'];
$competitorList = '';
foreach($competitor_names as $competitorList) {
    $competitorList = $competitorList.', ';
}
```

Comment: Form input arrays, have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314567/how-to-get-form-input-array-into-php-array

Comment: Try `$competitorList = implode(', ',$competitor_names);`

Comment: You use $competitorList for two different things. Probably you want to rename one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `implode()` seems to be what you're looking for :

```
$competitor_names = $_POST['competitor-name'];
$competitorList = implode(',', $competitor_names);
```

Comment: Thank you! This works great.