# Send multiple fields on form

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I am developing a system for equipment rental in PHP.

I need to send a form that contains the id, quantity, time and value fields of the selected equipment.
Each rent can have N equipments, consequently N amount of fields.

How do I do this? Do I generate the fields by javascript? To send, an array for each piece of equipment?

**It would be something like that:**

```
<input type='text' name='equipment[]'>
<input type='text' name='quantity[]'>
<input type='text' name='time[]'>
```

**But how would I do it like this:**

```
array(array[0](equipment=>1,quantity=>2,time=>4),array[1](equipment=>2,quantity=>2,time=>4),array[2](equipment=>1,quantity=>2,time=>4));
```

Comment: Can you share some code of what you've tried to so far?  You likely need to use an array for the form fields https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314567/how-to-get-form-input-array-into-php-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could group by rental doing like this:

```
<div id="rental_group_1">
    <input type="text" name="rent_1[]" id="equipment_1">
    <input type="text" name="rent_1[]" id="quantity_1">
    <input type="text" name="rent_1[]" id="time_1">
</div>
<div id="rental_group_2">
    <input type="text" name="rent_2[]" id="equipment_2">
    <input type="text" name="rent_2[]" id="quantity_2">
    <input type="text" name="rent_2[]" id="time_2">
</div>...
```

This way you will get on Post an array per group so:

```
$rent_1[0] = equipment_1
$rent_1[0] = quantity_1
$rent_1[0] = time_1
...
```

Adding this to @Blesson Christy solution will create a good UI/UX for what you want.
Hope it helps! :D

Answer (score 0):

A small example :

HTML:

```
 <div id="content">
<input type="text" class="fieldone" id="fields_1" name="fields[]"/>

</div><input type="button" id="addmore" />
```

Jquery:

```
counter=1;
$(document).on('click','#addmore',function(){
counter++;
var htmltoadd='<input type="text" class="fieldone" id="fields_"'+counter+' name="fields[]"/>';
$("#content").append(htmltoadd);
});
```

You need to include jquery in this example.