# How to take textbox value in php if created by js

Tags: php

I am using following code to generate multiple textbox on label click, it works correctly and multiple textbox created with different name. I want to take the value of textbox at php side and run insert query for each textbox. But i don't know how to use it in php. Here is my code plz help.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>

</title>
<script>
   var index = 1;
    function insertRow(){
        var table=document.getElementById("rep1");
        var row=table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
        var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
        var t1=document.createElement("input");
            t1.id = "txtName"+index;
            t1.name = "txtName"+index;
            cell1.appendChild(t1);
   index++;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<label id="btnAdd" style=" width: 10px;" class="button-add" onclick="insertRow();">add</label>
<table  id="rep1">

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

SQL Schema :

```
T_no(AI)     Text_value
```

PHP CODE:

```
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
 {
     $t1=$_POST['name'];// i am confused here how to take value and run query for all
 ?>
```

Comment: please have a look on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314567/how-to-get-form-input-array-into-php-array)

Comment: @JigarShah i saw the link. But there was only 2 array element. I want to use foreach for 7 arrays or multiple arrays.

Comment: okay, I have shared the link so you can get idea to start making changes to your code

Comment: @JigarShah thanks for the link you suggest it works for multiple array

Answer (score 2):

**Client side Code**

You must use `Array` for multiple name field

```
<script>
   var index = 1;
    function insertRow(){
        var table=document.getElementById("rep1");
        var row=table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
        var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
        var t1=document.createElement("input");
            t1.id = "txtName"+index;
            t1.name = "txtName[]"; //Use array of names not id
            cell1.appendChild(t1);
   index++;
}
</script>
```

Please check [How to get form input array into PHP array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314567/how-to-get-form-input-array-into-php-array)

And You can fetch those array server side using `$_POST['txtName'];` or any other request method

**Server side coding for inserting array into database**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{ 
    $t2=$_POST['txtName']; 
    $query_parts = array();
    $qu = "INSERT INTO try VALUES";
    foreach($t2 as $val)
    {

         $query_parts[] = "('', '" . $val . "')";
    }
    $qu .= implode(',', $query_parts);
    $res=mysqli_query($con,$qu);
    if(!$res) { echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con)); } 

}
?>
```

> The above code will not prevent data from [SQl injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection).You can use prepared statement for prevent SQL injection in PHP. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Yes what you suggest is working, but i am not able to send value via query. Will you please help

Comment: please show how you are sending those values @Shalini

Comment: if(isset($_POST["submit"]) {
       $t2=$_POST['txtName'];
       $qu="INSERT INTO `try` VALUES ('','$t2')";
 $res=mysqli_query($con,$qu);
 if($res)
  {
   
   echo '<script>alert("Data Saved Successfully");</script>';
  }
  else
  {
   echo "Error:".mysqli_error($con);
   
   exit();
   echo '<script>alert("Error Saving Data. Check Data and try Again!!");</script>';
  }
}

Comment: ok you are inserting whole array please use foreach or other loop for inserting multiple data.An array can not be stored in database

Comment: ya i use this code it work. but what if there is 2 different textbox then how to execute for each loop for them. if used: foreach ($t2 as $value )
{
$qu="INSERT INTO `try` VALUES ('','$value')";
 $res=mysqli_query($con,$qu);}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164524/discussion-between-vishnu-bhadoriya-and-shalini).

Comment: This code is **wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)**. You should really use **[Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)** instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all! You should also refrain from using bold, unless you what to emphasize something specific.

Comment: @vishnu will you please be on chat so that i can take help from you on my query

Comment: anyone suggest how to run foreach loop multiple time

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya do i add columns by using your previous code

Comment: Please do futher messages or comment here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165198/discussion465

Answer (score 1):

Use this code. It will helps you.

```
<?php 
print_r($_POST['txtName']); // Here you can get you all values.
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>

</title>
<script>
   var index = 1;
    function insertRow(){
        var table=document.getElementById("rep1");
        var row=table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
        var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
        var t1=document.createElement("input");
            t1.id = "txtName"+index;
            t1.name = "txtName[]"; // Use array in textbox name..
            cell1.appendChild(t1);
   index++;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="" >
        <label id="btnAdd" style=" width: 10px;" class="button-add" onclick="insertRow();">add</label>
        <table  id="rep1">

        </table>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should include an explanation about _why_ the OP should try this. What have you changed? What issue does it solve?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thats for suggestion

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to store total index value also(that should specify how many time you created input field).After that your php code should be like below..

PHP CODE:

```
 <?php
     if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
     {
     $t1=$_POST['txtName'.$index]; 
     ?>
```

Where index variable will your current index value from your loop for length of total input fields

Comment: Use of undefined constant index

Comment: Create hidden field in your php code.Create one variable to store total index value in your javascript insertRow() after that put that variable value in your hidden input field value.Now you are able to fetch this hidden field value in your PHP code and by this you could apply loop in before  **$t1=$_POST['txtName'][index];**

Comment: This answer is not going to work. If you look at the OP's code (`t1.name = "txtName"+index;`), the fields will be called `txtName1, txtName2, txtName3, etc` and won't be an array.

Comment: I edited my answer and comments like this - Create hidden field in your php code.Create one variable to store total index value in your javascript insertRow() after that put that variable value in your hidden input field value.Now you are able to fetch this hidden field value in your PHP code and by this you could apply loop in before  **$t1=$_POST['txtName'.$index];**