# Foreach loop update sql

Tags: php, mysql

I want a loop, that echoes some football matches and my users bets on them, and then the possibillity to change the bets.
I have two tables in my db:

`vm_kampe` which is the matches where `res` is the result:

```
|id |hhold   |uhold   |res  |
|1  |Rusland |Saudi   |NULL |
|2  |Egypten |Uruguay |NULL |
... and so on
```

and `vm_kampe`, which is the users bets:

```
|id |resu |
|1  |2-1  |
|2  |1-3  |
... and so on.
```

My update site is like this:

```
SELECT * FROM vm_kampe k JOIN vm_207 u ON k.id = u.id
...
foreach($results as $row){

echo '<div class="vm_kupon_row">    
<div class="vm_id"><input type="hidden" name="kampids[]" value="'.$row->id.'"></div>    
<div class="vm_kampe">'.$row->hhold.' - '.$row->uhold.'</div>
<div class="vm_result"><input class="vm_resultat" type="text" name="resultats['.$row->id.']" placeholder="X-X" value="'.$row->resu.'"></div>
<input type="submit" class="godkend-vm-kupon" name="submit['.$row->id.']" value="Godkend">
```

My POST site is like this:

```
$res = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['resultats']);
$id = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['kampids']);
FOREACH ($_POST as $p) {    
$gid = $p['id'];    
$result = $p['res'];    
$sql = "UPDATE vm_207 SET resu = '$result' WHERE id = '$gid'";    
};
```

But if I try editting a bet and press submit, the bet will just stay the same as before. All I want is for me to be able to update every match. Please help :)

***UPDATE***
I just tried this in the post code:

```
$id = $_POST['kampids'];
$res = $_POST['resultats'];
foreach ( $id as $key => $k) {
print "The match is " .$k. " and the result is " .$res[$key];
};
```

I tried writing 2-1 in the first game and the print was:

> The match is 1 and the result is 2-1 
>   The match is...

So as I can see, the function works, so now I just need it to update the table..

Comment: In your post code, you never execute the SQL statement.

Comment: Apart from the common remarks about bind parameters, just setting an `$sql` variable is not enough. You have to actually execute the statement.

Comment: Also check the loop there. I'm not sure this makes sense: `$result = $p['res'];`. $p is a single post variable (for instance, `resultats`), which may be an array, but it won't be a key-value array.   Long story short, try to figure out what *actually* happens, for instance by outputting variables using `var_dump` and see if they match your expectations. I think you will find some obvious issues that you've overlooked now.

Comment: btw, this is 2 different files - don't know if that means anything. But I thought the `$sql` was executed in the post code, when pressing submit in the edit code? I don't know how to use `var_dump` but I'll try to read about it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your hidden field, you are not setting the index number statically like you are with the other inputs.

```
<div class="vm_id"><input type="hidden" name="kampids['.$row->id.']" value="'.$row->id.'"></div>
```

I think this question / answer should help.

[How to get form input array into PHP array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314567/how-to-get-form-input-array-into-php-array)

Comment: Oh, i did that now :) Okay, I'll take a look at the Q/A. I'm not so good at this, but when I want an query instead of a print, i'll just write the query in the `foreach{}`?

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_POST)` to see how your POST variables are coming back. That will help you debug this further.

Comment: Please see my edit in the question :) Just tried printing it and it gets the right result, so I just need it to update the table now ..