# Submit List of Objects in PHP Form

Tags: php

I am trying to use a form to post multiple of the same object in PHP, but I can't get my head around a decent approach. Being a C# Developer, I would have my controller take in a List, but with PHP I can't work out quite how to do it.

**Example form**

Person: Anne Frank
Subject: English
Grade: A

Person: Steven Seagull
Subject: Maths
Grade: C

Person: Jeff Banks
Subject: English
Grade: F

---

Essentially I have a list, which has a select list, and a free text field, I want to be able to update and insert into the database with one submit.

Any suggestions for how I can approach this?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314567/how-to-get-form-input-array-into-php-array

Comment: In javascript use json format to get all the selected values and put it in your text field. Then you can submit the field value.