# Laravel - Store multiple checkbox form values in database

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-5

So I've got this code

**View:**

```html
<div id="checkboxes">
                         <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="services" value="{{ $service->id }}" id="{{ $service->id }}" />
                         <label class="whatever" for="{{ $service->id }}"><p class="serv-text"> {{ $service->service_name }} + ${{ $service->price }} </p></label>
                             </div>
```

**Controller:**

```html
  public function store(Request $request)
    {
       orders::create(Request::all());
        return 'test';
    }
```

**Model:**

```html
class orders extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
    'category', 
    'services',
    'total_price',
    'user_id',
    'status',
    'user_id'];
}
```

When I try to submit the form, in the database at services there is only one number even if I checked multiple boxes when I submitted the form.
I've tried to find on google a solution but nothing.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you have multiple checkboxes like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="services" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="services" value="2"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="services" value="3"/>
```

It will send's only one value to server, cause name must be unique. Workaround is to use array inputs:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="2"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="3"/>
```

Then you can grab that input in controller and do something like this:

```
$services = $request->input('services');
foreach($services as $service){
 orders::create($service);
}
```

Validation of arrays in Laravel:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#validating-arrays

More about input arrays:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#Handling_multiple_checkboxes

[How to get form input array into PHP array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314567/how-to-get-form-input-array-into-php-array)