# How can I save the value of my <input type='checkbox'> to MySQL Database with laravel 5.7 code?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

checkbox

```html
<div class="form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" name="IF" class="form-check-input"> 
    <label for="IF" class="form-check-label">Ingénieurie de formation</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="DS" class="form-check-input"> 
    <label for="DS" class="form-check-label">Diagnostique Stratégique</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="PF" class="form-check-input"> 
    <label for="PF" class="form-check-label">Plan de formation</label>
 </div>
```

---

and for my textbox I store it like this

```
$cl = new Client;
$cl->tel_1 = $request->input('tel_1');
```

Comment: Who is `tel_1` ? You should pick by input `name` attribute means `$request->input('DS');`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52447160/4968657

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the value wrong, the index is the `name` attribute in html:

`$cl->tel_1 = $request->input('IF');`

or

`<input type="checkbox" name="tel_1" class="form-check-input">`
and
`$cl->tel_1 = $request->input('tel_1');`

Answer (score 0):

Use value of name attribute from checkbox.

$checkbox1 = Input::get('IF') //name="IF"

also, do not forget to add.

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

Answer (score 0):

You can either use

```
$cl->tel_1 = $_POST['IF'];
```

Or you can use

```
$cl->tel_1 = $_REQUEST['IF'];
```

as well.