# Unable to populate cell by zero value from $_GET array

Tags: php, html

I am having an issue - I am unable to get a td cell when my $v value is 0. For all other numbers it is fine, but with zero value I just don't get then td.. What could be wrong? I am using $_GET array with a foreach loop, taking data from two inputs, one for name, one for value.

```
<table border = "1" >
<?php 
print_r($_GET); 
foreach ($_GET as $k=>$v){
    if($v){
        if ($rowFinished) echo "<tr>";

        if (preg_match("/{$inputVardas}/i", $k))
        {
           echo "<td>$v</td>";
           $rowFinished = false;
        }
        else if (preg_match("/{$inputSkaicius}/i", $k) and is_numeric($v))
        {
            if ($v < 10)
            {
                $color="green";
            }
            else if ($v > 10)
            {
                $color="red";
            }
            else if( $v == 10){
                $color="yellow";
            }

            echo "<td style='color: $color'>$v</td>";
            $rowFinished = true;
        }
        if ($rowFinished) echo "</tr>";
    }
}?></table>
```

I've tried to do some print_r of an array, there I can see a value, but in my loop it just doesn't work. Maybe it has to do something with the case that php treats it as empty, but I am unable to find a way to use it.

```
 [vardas0] => jonas [value0] => 0
```

Comment: +1 fpr using print_r() to verify the contents.  SUGGESTIONS: 1) Verify `if($v)` is true, 2)  Check `$rowFinished`.  3) Check both `preg_match()`

Comment: I used print_r, and the result with zero is like I've shown in my question.. It is zero. Could you be more specific with your suggestion?

Comment: Well, by doing `if($v)` and if `$v` is a zero (string or int, doesnt matter), then that `if` block will be skipped, since zero is falsey.

Comment: You may be better off creating arrays of values from your input on the HTML side - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314567/how-to-get-form-input-array-into-php-array.

Comment: Based on this: `[vardas0] => jonas [value0] => 0 `, I didn't get that `_GET[0]` was the value "0" ... which is equivalent to *FALSE*.  Which was actually the whole problem.  Doh!  Glad you figured it out ... and glad you figured out a way to distinguish "false" from the digit "0" ;)

Answer (score 2):

Directly after the `foreach` you have a `if ($v)`, and if the value is 0, it will not run.

Comment: You could improve your answer by giving an example that will work like he/she wants it too.

Comment: I could, and if required I will, but since the asker put the if statement there themselves, I am not sure what the wanted situation is. Why is this if here, what is it supposed to do?

Comment: Good question ;)

Comment: Thank you for answers. The situation is I would like to put 0 values also. Using just $v in if was my mistake. Thanks for pointing it. I already posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way by improving the following line from

```
if($v){
```

to

```
if($v or (is_numeric($v) and $v == 0)){
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using this

```
if ($v) {
```

to check that `$v` has a value. You can use

```
if (strlen($v)) {
```

instead.

Everything in `$_GET` will be a string, but a string '0' will evaluate as false just like an int 0 as you have discovered. Checking the length of the string instead will tell you whether or not that URL parameter has any value, including '0'.

You may also want to consider trimming the value before checking it if you want to exclude values containing only whitespace.

```
$v = trim($v);
if (strlen($v)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I honestly would suggest using `isset()`instead of all the provided suggestions so far. The reason is that to me it is best practice to have your conditionals be a boolean expression or something that explicitly evaluates to true or false. This avoids ambiguity and unintended side effects as evidenced by this question.

I would personally use:

```
if(isset($v)){
```