# Cloning input fields with array name only get the first value in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I clone my input fields using jquery. and get the value in PHP using var_dump first

**Example**

```
<form action="save.php" method="POST">
<div id="div-container">
 <div class="div-clone">
   <input name="name[]">
   <input name="bday[]">
   <input name="address[]">
   <input name="gender[]">
 </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

Now when then I'm cloning it using

```
$('#div-container').append($('#div-clone').get(0).outerHTML);
```

PHP CODE

```
if(isset($_POST['SUBMIT'])
{
 var_dump($_POST);
}
```

Does this result the array key value is also the same as the first one? because I only get one value
and only the first one. Is there any way to solve this?

Thanks

**EDIT**
I already getting data from my form my only problem is the input array that I clone. it's only getting the first value.

**EDIT AGAIN**
When I try to add just input with the same name of an array without cloning its works perfectly. Any solution regarding this? Thanks

Comment: **ID must be unique!**

Comment: huh? like I said I want them to be array. That's why I put `[]`

Comment: use **class** instead

Comment: what do you mean by use class?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I already cloning them my problem is my array on input they just output the first one only.

Comment: see this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314567/how-to-get-form-input-array-into-php-array the difference on the link is I'm cloning them using jquery but I only get the first input

Comment: _"The outerHTML property sets or returns the HTML element and all it's content, including the start tag, it's attributes, and the end tag."_ so you are appending a complete clone of that div, included "id" attribute. So that you will have two divs with the same id, that is not admitted

Comment: Your submit button has no `value` so `isset($_POST['SUBMIT'])` will never be true

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan edited it.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly remove the `id` from the content you want to clone. If you don't you'll end up with duplicates which is invalid and can cause issues in JS and the UI. A better approach is to use classes.

In addition, if you want to copy elements simply use `clone()`. Try this:

```js
$('button').on('click', () => $('.div-clone:first').clone().appendTo('#div-container'));
```

```css
input { width: 100px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Clone</button>
<div class="div-clone">
  <input name="name[]">
  <input name="bday[]">
  <input name="address[]">
  <input name="gender[]">
</div>  
<div id="div-container"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Sir, Did you try to dump the data to PHP?

Comment: No. If you want to do that wrap the fields in a `<form>` tag and submit it to your PHP page. If you're struggling with that I'd suggest starting a new question

Comment: Have you tested this? Where is your PHP code? How are you sending the data?

Comment: I already getting all my data to PHP using `var_dump` for now to check the data, the problem is just the input array that I clone is only geting the first value. I'll edit it to be a form.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Does this code not fix that issue?

Comment: It doesn't sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Output from your code is

```
array(4) {
  ["name"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  ["bday"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  ["address"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  ["gender"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
}
```

So it's correct. I cloned once, so I get two arrays of "name", two arrays of "bday" etc.
I guess that you want another format, this is a little trickier I think. Try this:

```
<button id="clone">Clone</button>

    <form method="POST">
        <div id="div-container">
            <div class="div-clone">
                <input data-field="name" name="data[0][name]">
                <input data-field="bday" name="data[0][bday]">
                <input data-field="address" name="data[0][address]">
                <input data-field="gender" name="data[0][gender]">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <pre>
    <?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        var_dump($_POST);
    }
    ?>
    </pre>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var i = 0;
        $('button#clone').on('click', () => {
            const clone = $('.div-clone:first').clone();
            i++;
            clone.find('input').each(function() {
                const fieldname = $(this).attr('data-field');
                $(this).attr('name', 'data[' + i + '][' + fieldname + ']');
            });
            clone.appendTo($('#div-container'));
        });
    </script>
```

This will give you the following output for one clone.

```
array(1) {
  ["data"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["bday"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["address"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["gender"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(4) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["bday"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["address"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["gender"]=>
      string(1) "2"
    }
  }
}
```

The field name is exactly the PHP-Array structure. Using name[] is just an array counting up. But I think all four fields should make one entry. So you have to make *one* entry (named data), make it an array, which is counted up (by "i") and then you add the field name (name, bday etc.)

Comment: do you mean if you use my currently code the output is getting an array? why mine getting just the first one after cloning them. I'm quite confused because when I didn't clone them I manually added another form its getting all the array that I input

Answer (score 0):

After messing around for so many times I solved it.

It seems on my framework that there's a UI error that make my form end on the near div element after cloning. Thank you for all your answer. all your answer is right so I'll upvote them. Thank you.