# Update custom $cart_item on Cart page with input field

Tags: php, ajax, woocommerce

I have a form on a non-shop page which when submitted, takes the inputs and adds a product in the cart programmatically with some custom `$cart_items` like so:

```
WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $prodID, 1, 0, array(), array(
  'bridgeName'       => $_POST['bridge_name'],
  'prodWidth'        => $_POST['prod_width'],
) );
```

These `$cart_item`s get added properly in backend as intended.
Now to display them, in the `cart.php` template, I have used these custom `$cart_items` through this code:

```
<?php echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '<p style="margin-bottom: 0;">%s</p>', esc_html( $cart_item['bridgeName']) ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>
......
......
<label for="prodWidth">Structure Width</label>
<input type="number" style="width: 10rem;" name="cart[<?php echo $cart_item_key; ?>][prodWidth]" id="strHeight_cart" value="<?php echo $cart_item['prodWidth']?>">
```

**Result:**
[image]

How do I make it so when I enter a new value in these input fields and click on **Update Cart** button, the `$cart_item['prodWidth']` gets updated in the backend and also populates these input fields with the updated value.

I also tried this, but it is not updating the `$cart_item['prodWidth']`:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_update_cart_action_cart_updated', 'my_cart_custom_fields' );
function my_cart_custom_fields( $cart_updated ){

    $contents = WC()->cart->cart_contents;
    foreach ( $contents as $key => $item ) {
        $contents[$key]['prodWidth'] = $_POST['cart['.$key.'][prodWidth];
    }

    return $cart_updated;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can have arrays in forms.  This might be worth looking at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314567/how-to-get-a-form-input-array-into-a-php-array

Comment: That is not what I am asking. I need the custom $cart_item values to be processed on the 'Update Cart' back-end request and update their respective values.

Comment: $contents[$key]['prodWidth'] = $_POST['cart['.$key.'][prodWidth]'] ? ;

Comment: Thanks, but I managed to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It was a typo I believe and now everything works as intended. Thanks.